# How can I use a variable, as a data 'name' in jQuery ajax?

Tags: jquery

Title is probably poor but I can't think of how to explain this.

I have an ajax that works:

```
var inputName = $('#input').prop('name');

$.ajax({
    url: 'file.php?'+inputName+'=0&uID='+uid+'',
    type: 'POST'
});
```

As you can see, the variable name alters and is set previously.

I end up with a post url being sent something like:

```
file.php?someName=0&uID=291
```

But I prefer the following kind of format, as to me it is more readable and less code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'file.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { '+inputName+': 0, uID: '+uid+' },
});
```

The problem is however, I end up with a request url like:

```
file.php?'+inputName+'=0&uID=291
```

Or if I put data: { inputName: 0 } etc, then 'inputName' is simply the variable name instead.

Is it possible to achieve what I'd like to do, using a variable as a key? If so how? Or should I stick with the longwinded ?'s and &'s?

Comment: what is your goal? if i were clear on that we may be able to help better

Comment: oh nevermind, i understand now. I know eval() is the devil, but have you tried using something like that?

Comment: If '+uid+' is working and '+inputName+'' is not, I can't see any other reason but an undeclared value.

Comment: @MelanciaUK because the OP doesn't want the literal key '+inputName+' he wants the value of the variable inputName to be used as a key. You can't do that in object literal notation, the object will have to be created as a separate step and the property added, as in adeneo's answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To use variables as keys in objects, you need to use bracket notation :

```
var obj = {uID: uid};
    obj[inputName] = 0;

$.ajax({
    url: 'file.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: obj
});
```

Comment: I've never seen anything like it. Trying it now.

Comment: nice, this is the way to go

Comment: Are you sure that is correct? Syntax is marking an error in that obj var with the 2nd colon. Browser is saying "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier".

Comment: @cosmicbdog - typo, hit a colon instead of the semicolon on my keyboard when writing that code, fixed now!

Comment: That's the business! Thanks!